# Comment with one rep without participation in post

Tags: support, comments, reputation

Is there any explanation for why the first comment on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/89934/54298) has been made by a user with 1 rep and no participation on that thread? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Yes there is a simple explanation...*

This was flagged because it was really a comment.

Since its the Mods that can see flags, this answer was converted to a comment for the post in question.  The answer itself was marked for deletion.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Mods are awesome!

Comment: Hear hear to that, ---although responsiveness to the flags queue could be better---

Comment: @LordofTime ... I was out for a few days, did you miss me that much? ;)